# Php copy CPU consumption

Tags: php, javascript, cpu

I am creating a site which allows users to view a file via JavaScript plugin.

To do this, and maintain the security of the file, I will be creating a one time unique copy of the original file, each time the JavaScript plugin is accessed.

The original file is at the maximum 30mb, how will this scale for multiple users of the system? Say if 100 people were to create and access the copy of the file.

Comment: I can't imagine any case where it would be unsafe to use the original file as long as you don't use write accesses?

Comment: @bwoebi What OP mentions might be useful in a scenario where someone would create a service providing music/sounds, but to make sure that they can't just copy paste the URL to the MP3, and then have the MP3 served to them (or share the link to the MP3 file).

Comment: @h2ooooooo mod_rewrite to a central PHP file which can access the other data on the disk?

Comment: @bwoebi Agreed - copy is by no means the way to do this. A rewrite and a PHP verification of eg. a download token is 1000 times better.

Comment: Could you show me an example of this?

Comment: The plugin needs read and write access, but of course this means through direct linkage they will be able to bypass our purchasing process, and download the file for free. The purpose of copy would be to create the file, and then remove it once the user has read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a htaccess rewrite to refer the user to a PHP script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+) /lib/download.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

This will forward any request to `yourdomain.com/download/anyfilehere.mp3?one_time_token=ABCDEFG` to `lib/download.php` and set the `$_GET['file']` to be `anyfilehere.mp3`. The `one_time_token` `$_GET` parameter will be forwarded, as we used `[QSA]`.

The `download.php` could simply look something like this:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET['file'])) {
        if (!empty($_GET['one_time_token'])) {
            if (TokenOK($_GET['one_time_token'])) { //Create a function called TokenOK where you look up the download token in eg. a database
                $fileName = '/var/www/downloadfolder/' . $_GET['file'];
                if (file_exists($fileName)) {
                    ExpireToken($_GET['one_time_token']); //Create a function called ExpireToken where you expire the token in eg. the database
                    readfile($fileName); //Read the file to the user
                    die();
                } else {
                    die('Error: file not found');
                }
            } else {
                die('Error: token is not OK');
            }
        } else {
            die('Error: token is not specified');
        }
    } else {
        die('Error: file is not specified');
    }
?>
```

**Things to consider:**

- Output a mime header type specifying the content-type of your file
- Read [this PHP manual entry on `readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
- Limit the one time token to only be valid in a certain time frame (and notify your user of this), instead of allowing it to be downloaded only once
- How will your system react if the user *cancels* the download, and therefore can't download it again?
- What if the download fails? Do they need to request a new download link?
- If it's a streaming MP3 file, make sure that seeking works (it most likely won't if you seek outside where the MP3 has streamed to, as it'll create a new request for the MP3 file)

Comment: How do I implement the token? Is there a php specific function?

Comment: @James It shouldn't be too hard to generate a random ID and put it in a database (use `uniqid` if you have to), and then send that ID to the user and use it for the link. Your database should be `id | token | ip | valid` or `id | token | ip | valid_until` based on which approach you use. IP is optional, but might be nice so you can see if one user is downloading the same file a billion times.

Comment: Thank you very much, love you a lot hahaha :)